# change backgroundColor For every item when using map in react.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, api, sass

I get objects from api , i get it and mapping over it and return `<p></p>` like this:

```
data.map((item) => <p> {item.p} </p> )
```

my question is: how can i give every paragraph a diffrent backgrounColor from each other?

Comment: Use CSS and add a bespoke class to each new paragraph, or adjust the paragraph's `style.backgroundColor` directly with a CSS name/hex value of your choice.

Comment: Create a Map where keys are your items and values are your custom colors. Use foreach and dont forget to provide key attribute for your p tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make different colors for each element in the following way

```
data.map((item) => <p style={{ backgroundColor: `#${((Math.random() * 0xfffff * 1000000).toString(16)(.slice(0,6)}` }}> {item.p} </p> )
```

Comment: it worked but what if i have just three colors and i want to use them not randomaly?

Comment: You can grid a number between 1-3 in the following way:
`function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
};
const rndInt = randomIntFromInterval(1, 3)`;

Then if we say your array of colors is called arrColors, then print:
 `style={{ backgroundColor: \`{arrColors[rndInt]}\` }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a colour variable associated with each item

```
data.map((item) => <p style={{backgroundColor: item.color}}>{item.p}</p>);
```

or you can do it randomly

```
data.map((item, index) => <p style={{backgroundColor: `#43f${index}FC`}}>{item.p}</p>);
```